How to make an arrow leap over another to prevent their intersections in Tikz?
I am using \usepackage{tikz} to draw a flow chart where the arrows are created using \draw [arrow] command, I have a situation where the arrows intersect and thus direction may be confusing. I want to prevent them from intersection and hence create a leap of one over the other.
The example of the error is attached here:

How to achive that?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide some code others can use. Maybe this can already help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399857/47927

Also take a look at the spath3 library which can semiautomate this for arbitrary paths.

you can also look for examples of knots, which are the kind of case spath3 is designed for (lots of leaping lines).

what if I don't want to use third party tex libraries? is there a latex - Tikz native solution?

@PatrickSchulz Via the link I provided above, there are solutions that work with just TikZ. All packages for TeX (including TikZ) are in one sense or the other "third party", so please define what you mean by that. Typically, one would say, everything that is available on CTAN is part of one of the major TeX distributions (which I would argue is the main point here).

I am gettting the error undefined control sequence for \tikztostart and \tikztotarget

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->, preaction={draw=white, -, line width=6pt}] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



great!thanks!!! how it knows where the intersection is so that it draws it in a white line?

If you want to see what is happening, try to change white to red.
